# Google Dialogflow / Twilio Voice - How to connect caller with human?

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, twilio-api, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

we are using Twilio Voice and Google Dialogflow and their NodeJS SDk.

Once the default fallback intent has been triggered in Dialogflow, we are executing the Webhook to our Server - this should connect the caller with a real human.

- Webhook is not a problem
- How can we redirect/connect the current call with a number, specified by us?

I have read the documentation but I was not able to find a solution.

This is something we have tried so far:

```
    twilioClient.calls
  .create({
    url: 'https://ourdomain.de/redirect-xyz.xml',  instructions
    to: numbertoCall,
    from: '+ourPhone'
  })
  .then(call => console.log(call.sid))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

The xml file simply contains

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>+NumberWeWantToCall</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

I only get "An application error has occured. Am i missing something?
Can someone help me with a solution?

I highly appreciate it, thank you!